# CSS pseudoclass problems with touch screen

Tags: html, css, touch

I have a very simple CSS over `button` element. Here it is:

```
.button {
    background-color: #5266ed;
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
}

.button:active {
    background-color: #6fa0ed;
}
```

It works totally fine when I click my `button` with mouse, but if I use monitor touch (DELL P2314T), `.button:active` does not apply. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a handler for all touch events to trigger it. I believe it's not working because of the touch delay on touch devices.

Add this to your body:

```
<body ontouchstart="">

</body>
```

Comment: But isn't it possible to do it with CSS only? Also, click handler triggers instantly.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. `:hover` will work but won't deselect the colour after clicking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the :focus function is your way out. Cause hover isn't work in case of touchscreen and

Comment: `:focus` does not dissappear when tap or click ended until new tap or click.